# C# Intersecting two rangers not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, debugging

I am trying to use two lists to determine if the list intersects each other.
[image]
As far as I am aware range one should not intersect with range two, so it should spit out an empty list. However as you can see in the list I am getting numbers that are never even included in the two ranges provided.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a weird bug? I have fed this to the OpenAI chatbot too and it agrees with me that this should not be happening. (Cool bot btw).

Thanks for any help!!!

The code:

```
public void Challenge2()
    {
        List<(Int32 min1, Int32 max1, Int32 min2, Int32 max2)> _numbers = new(){(64, 67, 43, 63)};
        Int32 count = 0;
        foreach ((Int32 min1, Int32 max1, Int32 min2, Int32 max2) in _numbers)
        {
            //if (min1 <= max2 && max2 > min2 || min2 <= max1 && max1 > min1)
            var s = Enumerable.Intersect(Enumerable.Range(min1, max1), Enumerable.Range(min2, max2));
            if (Enumerable.Intersect(Enumerable.Range(min1, max1), Enumerable.Range(min2, max2)).Any())
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(min1, max1)` parameters of this method are not minimum and maximum values of the range. But first parameter is minimum values and the second parameter is the count. So `Enumerable.Range(64, 67)` gives you the list of 67 numbers starting from 64. To solve your problem you should do `Enumerable.Range(min1, max1 - min1 + 1)`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the basic problem here is your understanding of the arguments to `Enumerable.Range`.  If you look at [the documentation for Enumerable.Range(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0), you'll see that the first `int` argument is the `start` number, and the second `int` argument is the `count`. Therefore, you should be creating your ranges like:

```
var intersection = Enumerable.Intersect(
    Enumerable.Range(min1, max1 - min1 + 1), 
    Enumerable.Range(min2, max2 - min2 + 1));
```

Also, there's no need to calculate it twice (you do it a second time in the `if` condition). It's not clear to me what your `count` variable is supposed to represent, but probabaly one of the following should apply:

```
if (intersection.Any())
{
    count++;
}

// Or just:
int count = intersection.Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, I really was scratching my head about this, and have been staring at it for ages. Completely missed the fact that Range takes a starting number and increments from there.

Also it's part of my Advent of Code challenge day 4. So the input normally would be larger and I needed to count the intersections.
https://adventofcode.com/